# Locate element in selenium webdriver , if the id is changing time to time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<span id=":of" class="gO aQY" data-tooltip="Select Contacts" aria-label="To - Select Contacts" role="link" tabindex="1">To</span>
```

How to locate element in selenium webdriver, here id will change time to time. So I need to locate by the aria label" to-select contacts"

Answer (score 3):

Get it *by xpath*:

```
//span[@aria-label="To - Select Contacts"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Css selector is my favorite choice. There are so many different attributes you can use to locate your element without using its ID.

Please read this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selectors. Smth like this:

```
//If class name is permanent and there is single instance on the page
driver.findElement(By.Css(".gO aQY"))
//otherwise
 driver.findElement(By.Css("span[aria-label='To - Select Contacts']"))
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) link for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this xpath

```
//span[@data-tooltip = 'Select Contacts']
```